# Как мне выводить все пароли из базы данных? sqlite3 aiogram

Tags: python, aiogram

Выводится только одна строчка, а у меня их всего 2 пока-что. Вот этим кодом я вывожу пароли:

```
db.conn.execute('select password from accounts').fetchall()[0]
```

Выводится только мой пароль.

Comment: Уберите в конце [0]. Вы берете только нулевой индекс, а если надо все, то [0] писать не надо

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
allpass=db.conn.execute('select password from accounts').fetchall()
for psswd in allpass:
    print(psswd)
```

Comment: `pass` ключевое слово, лучше выбрать что-то другое

Answer (score 0):

Помог ответ пользователя @nta, цитирую:

> Уберите в конце [0]. Вы берете только нулевой индекс, а если надо все, то [0] писать не надо